# Combined navigation and status bar. Android ROM

Tags: java, android, operating-system, android-7.1-nougat

I know I risk this question being flagged and closed by some good people on this platform but I have to ask anyway.

I have been trying to achieve a combined navbar and status bar for nougat tablets like the tablet mode of the Android 4 family. I have done a lot of searches but have found very little information, especially doing this for later versions of Android( 6 and up).

I have and am still asking on XDA developers since this question relates to the Android ROM, OS, and AOSP.

The least information I can get on how to achieve this will go a long way to make a difference and will be very much appreciated.  :)

Thanks already.

[This is the navbar I am referring to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbN35.png)

Comment: Yes, it's gonna be closed as too-broad. Sorry :)

Comment: Yes, Onik, I hope I get a good answer before then.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working on android 7.1. This can be achieved in the following ways.

1. Creating your combined status and navbar UI and hooking it to navigation services. Then editing system UI to hide both status and navigation bars simply by setting navbar and status bar heights to zero.
2. Using accessibility services for navigation, and hiding status and navbars.

I will update the answer with my code if as soon as I can. Hope this helps somebody.